# request get method with Korean language value make HTTP 400

Tags: jquery, asp.net, url, asp.net-core

When I make a search bar with ASP.NET Core, I got a problem.

First, I hava a `<input>` and button for it. Eg.

```
<input type=text id="text">
<input type="button" id=btn>
```

And there is a jquery like

```
$("#btn").click(function(e){
    var txt = $("#text").val();
    window.location.href = "/List?val=" + txt;
});
```

(If it is not a good way please let me know how to remake it)

So The List Controller like following

```
public class ListController{

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index(string val, string category)
    {
        if (val != null)
        {
            return `Dapper Query result` --- (1)
        }
    }
}
```

The real code is more complicate than it.

When I input `abc` in input box and click the button the process get in (1) and good work. (the url is `~/List?val=abc`)

But when I input `한글` which is korean language, the process do not get in (1) and browser shows **`HTTP 400 bad request`** (the url is `~/List?val=한글`)

Now.. how can I make it work? Thanks!

**Add**

I tested a new project with a simple action method like

```
public IActionResult Index(string str)
{
    return View();
}
```

And trying to access url like

`page.com/controller/Index?str=한글`

also shows **HTTP 400 bad request**

- Chrome has no problem. This problem only(I think) happen in IE

Comment: ~/List?val=한글 here value is string so need to wrap in quote. And it is better to use jquery-ajax rather than querystring

Comment: @Komal wrapping with quotation mark also does not work...

Comment: try to use encodeURIComponent(txt)

Comment: @Komal Thanks!!!